# Lexical and syntax analyzer software

Tags: c++, yacc, flex-lexer, analyzer, lexical

I am designing a custom language based on CSS-ish (CSS+custom extension) which basically would work like this:

```
[object.member.value = 5]{
object.member.anothervalue:8 
object.member.yetanothervalue:'hello'
object.member.yetyetanothervalue.anothervalue:blue
}
```

Basically the language allows to check for some conditions (if's, can be nested) and then apply some values to the object. There are no loops.
This would be stored in plain text files and loaded into the application (C++) at starting time.

**The idea is to translate this CSS-ish file into a C++ tree or something similar, which can be evaluated at runtime**.

I am considering using some lexical analyzers and tokenizers (Yacc, Flex, Bison, etc...).

What would be your suggestion of tools / libraries to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect to do this sort of thing more than once, learn how to use parser generators. It will save you a lot of pain in the long run.

Start simple. The tools will do lots of things for you, and generally with very little effort. Let them do that. Get things working before you try to do things which are complex.

The rest of this assumes that you will use `flex` and `bison` (which are `lex` and `yacc` lookalikes.) You don't have to; there are many alternatives. If you decide to try one of the other alternatives, ignore the rest of this answer.

But `flex` and `bison` are solid, well-maintained, well-debugged packages with a lot of documentation, and they've been used extensively over a long period of time. Read the documentation first.

- `flex` will read from standard input or a provided file descriptor automatically. Let it do that.
- `flex` will track line numbers for you. Let it do that.
- `bison` will generate token numbers for you automatically. Let it do that.
- `bison` and `flex` are optimized for single-character tokens. Not only do you not need to provide token numbers, you don't even need to provide token names. In your flex file, just put this at or near the end:

  ```
  . { return yytext[0]; }
  ```

  and don't bother writing rules to handle single-character tokens. Don't worry about the fact that you will tokenize illegal characters; `bison` will produce an error message for you.
- However, don't allow `flex` to insert a default rule. (`%option nodefault` is enough to suppress it.)

A couple of other tips:

- Even though `yytext` is a global, pretend that it isn't. You must copy any string which is needed for further processing. `strdup` is your friend; use it rather than messing around with `malloc` and `strcpy`. Use `asprintf` as well; `char* out; asprintf(&out, "%s%s%s", s1, s2, s3);` is far and away the easiest way to concatenate three strings. There are easily available unrestricted implementations for platforms which don't have these things, so don't worry about the "but they're not Posix/Standard C/yadda yadda yadda" arguments. And don't even think about fixed-length buffers. You don't need them. Honest.
- On the other hand, if a token can be processed in the scanner, do it there. Numbers, for example; it's much easier to do the `strtol` once in the scanner, and then you don't even need to think about memory allocations.
- Don't forget to `free()` strings when you don't need them any more, but if you find that difficult start by leaking memory and then fix things after you have your parser working. (I know some people will find that sacrilegious, but as long as you remember to do it before production, it's fine; you'll feel a lot more motivated once you have the basics working.)

And finally:

- Use a reasonably current version of `bison`. If you find yourself with mysterious shift/reduce conflicts, use a `glr` parser: yes, it's a bit slower, but if it saves you some pain, it's worth it. You can always go back and fix things up later. (GLR parsers won't save you from all grammar problems. You still need to make sure your grammar isn't ambiguous. But they can help.)
- My personal recommendation: Use the `C` interfaces. It's ok to compile with C++ and you can use standard C++ containers and other nice features; just don't use them in your semantic values because that doesn't play nicely with `bison`'s internal stack management. (Pointers to C++ containers are just fine, though.) And remember that `flex` and `bison` are just control flow; the bulk of your program is going to be written in C/C++, so you're not entering a new world by using the compiler tools. You're also not getting a free pass: you need to know how to use C/C++ before you start writing your parser.

Hope that helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

i would use a homemade scanner with a recursive descent parser because this is a very simple parsing task and using a parser generator would take as much or more time then writing the parser yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at **[Boost Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html)**, which allows you to write easily lexical analysers (Boost.Lex), and parsers (Boost.Qi) .  It has an interesting approach consisting of defining the syntax/grammar directly in the C++ code instead of using a separated grammar file.  It's portable, standard, self-contained and very elegant.

You could consided **Flex and Bison** if your language is going to evolve into something more complex.  They use the same kind of input files as Lex & Yacc, which are their older Unix equivalents.  The advantage of these tools is that there is plenty of litterature.  The inconvenient, is that they generate code by mixing their skeleton code with pieces that you give in the grammar files.  Hence, it's more complex to master and maintain.

But in your special case, you have a very simple language with only a couple of tokens and apparently a simple "LL(1) grammar". (e.g. the parser needs to read a single token ahead to determine without ambiguity what it is going to parse).  It would be easy to craft your own code, eventuell using [`<regex>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) to ease token scanning, and creating objects that correspond to your language structures.